# Session from express-session not persisting through requests

Tags: express, session, express-session

I'm using `express-session` and trying to implement a protected route with custom middleware.

[NOTE: I'm currently storing my session in-memory]

```js
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "f4z4gs$Gcg",
    cookie: { maxAge: 300000000, secure: true },
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    store,
  })
);

// MIDDLEWARE
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.session) //  This doesn't show the user and authenticated properties created in the POST login request
  if (req.session.authenticated) {
    return next();
  } else {
    res.status(403).json({ msg: "You're not authorized to view this page" });
  }
};

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  db.users.findByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
    if (user) {
      if (user.password === password) {
        // Add your authenticated property below:
        req.session.authenticated = true;
        // Add the user object below:
        req.session.user = {
          username,
          password,
        };
        // Send the session back to the client below:
        res.json(req.session); // Properties show up here
      } else {
        res.status(403).json({ msg: "Bad Credentials" });
      }
    } else {
      res.status(403).json({ msg: "No user found!" });
    }
  });
});


// PROTECTED ROUTE
app.get("/protected", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render("profile");
});
```

Once a user logs in successfully, I try to add two properties into `req.session`: `authenticated` and the `user` object. However, once I login and try to access `/protected` with the middleware, my session properties do not persist (no `user` or `authenticated` property). Am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but try setting secure to false.

Comment: That worked! Not sure why.

Comment: Going to add this is a solution, please mark it as one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting secure to false in the cookie object. If you want it to be httpOnly, then just set httpOnly to true.